# Rails efficiency on finding associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

I have an application with Users, Posts and Comments. Users has_many Posts, Posts has_many Comments and Comments belong_to Users and Posts.

In my view template I'm looping over the Comments like this to get the username of the commenter:

`User.find(comment.user_id).name`

How efficient is this if I'm doing this for every Comment per Post ?
I could imagine that it's maybe faster to store the username in a separate row in the Comments table, but duplicating the data seems just wrong.

Am I being paranoid and is ActiveRecord doing some caching magic or is there a better way of doing something like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preload the users in the initial query.
Seeing as you have the association setup between User and Comment you can access the user via the association.

Let's assume you have a controller method:

```
def show
  @posts = Post.limit(10).includes(:comments => :user)
end
```

In your view as you loop over `@comments`:

```
@posts.each do |post|
  # show post stuff
  post.comments.each do |comment|
    comment.user.name
  end
end
```

Comment: so, if i limit the posts returned (say 10), the `@comments` will only grab the users for the 10 returned posts ?

Comment: @daanVOS I updated my example. This loads ten posts and includes comments and the comment user all eagerly.

Comment: @daanVOS this way the app will likely make one SQL query for the posts, one for comments and one for the users who made those comments, regardless of how many comments there are.

Answer (score 0):

[Eager loading of associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Eager+loading+of+associations)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  # ...
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end


comments = @post.comments.includes(:user)
```

It will preload users.

SQL will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`post_id` = 42;
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) # 1,2,3,4,5,6 - user_ids from comments
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to load posts with comments with users with users posts?

Answer (score 0):

Revised

If you have association as below you can access user from comment object itself `comment.user`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Comment: Isn't this saying that the comment user is the same as the owner of the post the comment is associated to? In which case that would be totally wrong as surely many users can comment on another user's post?

Comment: @lebreeze, I have the same question

Comment: @cutalion both our answers are very similar and I'm almost certain they are correct. I'm not sure why they were down-voted as that's misleading to people who are genuinely trying to learn about Rails associations.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue for you, using a none relational DB, like Mongodb is the way to go.

If you still want to use ActiveRecord, either you use eager loading with `Post.comments.include(:user)` (which will load unused users info - and that's not great), or you can use **caching** techniques.

I find it OK to cache the `user.name` in the comments table, as you suggested, as long as you control the changes that can occur. You can do that by setting callbacks in your `User` model:

```
after_save do |user|
  Comment.where(user_id: user.id).update_all(:username, user.name)
end
```

This technique is sort of a DB caching, but, of course, you can cache HTML fragments. And a comment block is a good to cache HTML block.